# jquery .find issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm moving down a table using the up/down arrow keys.  I am manipulating the class of the `<tr>` tags to change the CSS class (highlighted/non-highlighted).  I noticed when the screen loads and I click the arrow keys the first time `tr_lst.attr('id')` has a value but after the 2nd click it says it is undefined.

I think it has something to do with the manipulation of the CSS in the javascript code.  Any ideas on how I can get this to print out a value after every keypress?

```
    var tr_lst = $('#' + ListBoxVal).find('tr[class="LUGridRowHighlight"]');
    console.log('tr_lst id: ' + tr_lst.attr('id'));
```

Comment: Your selector in `find` could be written more simply as `'tr.LUGridRowHighlight'`

Comment: Can you setup a test case @ jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Actually, @FishBasketGordo might of fixed my issue.  After I made that change my print statement started to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because my comment helped you, I'm posting it as an answer:

> Your selector in `find` could be written more simply as `'tr.LUGridRowHighlight'`.

Answer (score 1):

It probably is because you do not need to use `find()`:

```
var tr_lst = $('#' + ListBoxVal + " tr.LUGridRowHighlight");
console.log('tr_lst id: ' + tr_lst.attr('id'));
```